# Installing postgres 9.4 on ubuntu with a non-default database directory

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I am trying to install and set up postgres 9.4 on ubuntu 14.04.

What is the best way to install postgres whilst ensuring all created tables and databases (and anything else that could potentially occupy a lot of disk space) are stored at `/database`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd just remount whatever you've stuck at `/database` onto `/var/lib/postgresql`, because you're going to confuse the living heck out of anyone who has to deal with this frankenmachine in the future.  That being said, if you really want to move it, there's two ways forward:

- Make `/var/lib/postgresql` a symlink to `/database`.  Keeps the filesystem structure intact, at the cost of a symlink (which give some people the heebie-jeebies).
- The other way is a bit more involved, but arguably "more correct".  In this case, install *just* the `postgresql-common` package, before you install any of the other postgresql-related packages.  Then, edit `/etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf`, and change the line that sets `data_directory` so that it reads `data_directory = '/database/%v/%c'`.  So you'll need to uncomment it, then edit the value.  (While you're in there, you can also change `initdb_options` to specify a different character encoding and locale, if you want, and set `log_line_prefix` to something more readable...)

  *Then* install the `postgresql-9.4` package.  It'll pick up the custom value for `data_directory` and create the new cluster in there, instead of in the default location.